# Does the full disk encryption in the Ubuntu 18.04 installer encrypt all partitions?

Tags: 18.04, encryption

As title says, does the FDE option in the 18.04 installer (which is the only encryption option as the `home` only encryption has been dropped) encrypt the other partitions too? Will it break an existing Windows partition?

Comment: Yes, encrypts all. That's what "full" means. And yes, it will remove all the other partitions.

Comment: That makes a lot of stuff clear, thank you. Consider elaborating this with some sources and making an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I would rather let the experts do it.

Comment: My understanding is that it does not encrypt the boot partition. Paddy has been doing some work on manual full disk encryption: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399092https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399092

Comment: I'm fairly confident it doesn't encrypt anything but the root partition and swap. As the docs for it say, ["This page describes a way to set up an Ubuntu installation with a encrypted root partition and encrypted Swap."](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FullDiskEncryptionHowto) It would be quite odd for a Linux decryption process to run when Windows runs if there's no Linux kernel for it to run on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**"Full" Disk encryption**

I was eager to give 18.04's Full Disk Encryption a try.

With previous versions of Ubuntu, Full Disk Encryption did not work with flash drives.

After making an encrypted install to USB I examined the results with both Disks and GParted.

[image]

---

[image]

The encrypted extended partition was fully encrypted. Swap is a **file** within this partition, (and not a partition on it's own), and thus is also encrypted.

The Boot partition is **not** encrypted. The disk must first be booted before it can be decrypted.